# Modelo de Subnivel de Autorelacion en Django

Tags: django, django-models

Soy nuevo en el desarrollo bajo el framework de Django y no he encontrado una documentacion o tutorial que me especifique como traducir a modelos el diseño de datos que pasaré a especificar.

Como ejemplo sobresimplificado idearemos una cadena de produccion/montaje en el cual un producto puede depender/consumir X productos para su contruccion.

Estaría representado por la siguiente estructura:

[image: Diagrama de estructura de datos]

Que se traduciría en el siguiente SQL (en SQL Server):

```
CREATE TABLE [Producto] (
  [Id] Int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
  [Nombre] varchar(64) UNIQUE NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [RequisitoProducto] (
  [Id] Int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
  [Producto] Int,
  [ProductoRequerido] Int,
  [Cantidad] Int NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY ([Producto]) REFERENCES Producto([Id]),
  FOREIGN KEY ([ProductoRequerido]) REFERENCES Producto([Id]),
)
```

Pero no logro descifrar cual seria su representación en un modelo de Django, he probado con la siquiente interpretacion:

```
class Producto(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=64)
    
class Requerimiento(models.Model):
    producto = models.ForeignKey(
        Producto,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    productoRequerido = models.ForeignKey(
        Producto,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    Cantidad = models.DecimalField(blank=False, max_digits=2, decimal_places=0)
```

Pero exhibe el error (al ejecutar 'makemigrations'):

```
Produccion.Requerimiento.producto: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Requerimiento.producto' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Requerimiento.productoRequerido'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Requerimiento.producto' or 'Requerimiento.productoRequerido'.
Produccion.Requerimiento.productoRequerido: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Requerimiento.productoRequerido' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Requerimiento.producto'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Requerimiento.productoRequerido' or 'Requerimiento.producto'.
```

La pregunta es: ¿que modelo podría satisfacer dicho requerimiento estructural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es correcto. Sin entrar en diseño porque haría falta mas contexto.

#### solución rápida

Pasale `related_name=productos_requeridos` como parámetro en `Requerimiento.productoRequerido`.

```
class Producto(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=64)
    
class Requerimiento(models.Model):
    producto = models.ForeignKey(
        Producto,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    productoRequerido = models.ForeignKey(
        Producto,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        related_name='productos_requeridos'
    )
    Cantidad = models.DecimalField(blank=False, max_digits=2, decimal_places=0)
```

#### explicación

No olvides que `Django` tiene un maravilloso `ORM`. Ese mismo crea un conjunto de métodos que vas a utilizar o no, pero te los deja ya cocinados por si a caso.

En este caso, los `related_fields` son las relaciones a la inversa de las llaves foranas.

Por ejemplo, si llamamos a un producto `agua = Producto()`  , des de `agua.productos_requeridos.set()` podrás obtener la lista de todos los requerimentos donde  `Requerimiento.productoRequerido` lo es Agua.

#### tu error

Desde el punto de vista de la clase `Producto`, se relaciona dos veces con `Requerimiento`. Django por defecto añade el nombre de la clase como `related_name`, o sea el methodo de referencia inverso `Producto.requerimineto.set()`.  Lo que te pasa es que esta relación se produce dos veces, pero no pueden existir dos atributos con el mismo nombre. `Django` te sugiere que pongas tu el nombre que quieras. Yo te he puesto `productos_requeridos`.

#### práctica

```
agua = Producto(nombre='agua')
azucar = Producto(nombre='azucar')
sal = Producto(nombre='sal')


salado = Requerimiento(producto=agua,productoRequerido=azucar)
```

Comprueba que `agua.requerimiento.set()` existe y devuelve azúcar, al igual que `agua.productos_requeridos.set()`.

Y que `sal.requerimientos.set()` no devuelve nada, pues no esta en ningún requerimiento. Tampoco `sal.productos_requeridos.set()`.

[Documentación oficial Objetos de relaciones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/3.1/ref/models/relations/)

Comment: No existen las palabras para agradecer semejante exhibición explicativa, esperaré 2 días para asignarle una merecida recomensa a tu respuesta. Para confirmar que entendí, y en cortas palabras: "'related_name' asigna el nombre del método que retorna los registros relacionados a través de un campo foráneo", ¿es así?
Nuevamente, gracias.

Comment: Asi es!  El buen maestro existe cunado hay buen alumno ;)

Answer (score 1):

Como son dos Foreign Keys que apuntan a la misma entidad, debes definirle el atributo related_name para que el framework luego pueda identificar cuando estás llamando a cada una por separado.

```
class Requerimiento(models.Model):
producto = models.ForeignKey(
    Producto,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    blank=False,
    null=False,
    related_name = 'producto'
)
productoRequerido = models.ForeignKey(
    Producto,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    blank=False,
    null=False,
    related_name='productoRequerido'
)
```

PD: Yo siempre pongo en el related_name el mismo nombre del atributo. Alguna que otra vez me ha resuelto el problema